# Responsive video conflicting with DIV in CSS

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design, responsiveness

I have a responsive video on my page and I've set to to adjust to a static background image when the display reaches below 767px width (for smartphones).

Problem is, that anything between 768px to 1199px (width) eg. on iPads, my video DIV container height does not respond to, causing a white margin below the video. Ideally the container should adjust from 266px - 347px (height) in parallel with the video height/width.

.videobg is my container and .videoheader is the video itself.

Here is the code:

```
.videobg {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%; 
height:100%;
position: static;
z-index: -100;
min-height: 250px;
max-height: 423px;
}

.videoheader {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .videobg {
        background: url('images/home/header.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
        height:266px;
    }

    .videoheader {
        display: none;
    }
}


@media(max-width:768px){
.videobg {
height:266px;
     }
}

@media (max-width: 884px) {
    .videobg {
        height:280px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .videobg {
        height:347px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in addition to css?

Comment: Also, if you are trying to make responsive video player, try looking at this: https://jsfiddle.net/tboyvk5p/

Comment: @Green - sure - you can check it out here: www.zalmah.com/newsite

Comment: Sorry, I realize it's not a MCVE ... but it's the first time I've posted on stack exchange and will probably need a bit more time to get it down ;)

Comment: @Green I have tried object-fit:fill and object-fit: cover for the video. unfortunately neither have worked

Comment: Have you tried: https://jsfiddle.net/67akaqnt/
Make sure that `padding-top` will be set properly to fit ratio of your video.

Comment: @Green - thanks for the response - I don't have any padding. The video is responsive but the problem occurs just between a screen width of 767-1199px. Here is an image to explain: http://imgur.com/F8IF0On

Comment: @Green - When I use media queries, I am able to adjust the height of the container (.videobg) for specific widths of the video (.videoheader) but it is not scaling, so I am left with the white space below just on the screen widths of 767-1199px. http://www.zalmah.com/newsite/index.html

Comment: Yep, I know what you mean I was just trying to give you another solution for scaling with keeping ratio. How about `.videobg {font-size: 0px;}` then?

Comment: @Green - Thank you very much. Everything smooth now ;)

Comment: Glad to help, added answer to clean-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this certain case it looks that solution will be:

```
.videobg {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

I strongly recommend using other scaling for responsive videos (e.g. [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/67akaqnt/)) and, oh dear, so many media queries! :D
But, duh, if it works for you it's fine.